# Laravel multi language model translation

Tags: php, laravel

I have database field like this : `en_title`, `fr_title`

how do I translate title in model and how to show in blade

Comment: Laravel provides two ways to manage translation strings. **First**, language strings may be stored in files within the `resources/lang` directory. **Second**  ranslation strings may be defined within JSON files that are placed within the `resources/lang` directory. When taking this approach, each language supported by your application would have a corresponding JSON file within this directory . [see more](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization)

Answer (score 0):

you need to make 2 column one for English and one for French in this case you must take the 2 values from user that enter this titles like this


show it based on the user language .
but this is not good solution to make multi language website because if you need to add another language you will need to change in your table and in your code ( open close principal ) . good practice in this case to make table for language , post description ( that hold the column you need to translate it like title ) , then make relation ship between posts table and its descriptions